# Representation of of $SO(3)$ in the vector space $V = \mathbb C^{2S+1}$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Certain part in my textbook implies that a representation of $SO(3)$ in the vector space $V = \mathbb C^{2S+1}$, where $S \in \mathbb Z$, is possible. I am trying to find a path that leads to this representation. My reasoning is the following.

The induced Lie algebras $so(3)$ and $su(2)$ are isomorphic, so I can uniquely map an element of $so(3)$ into $su(2)$. Now by considering the representation of $SU(2)$ in a space of polynomial of fixed degree $l$ on $\mathbb C^2$, denoted by $P_l(\mathbb C^2)$, I can show that the induced Lie algebra $su(2)$ in $P_l(\mathbb C^2)$ has matrix form of size $(2S+1)\times(2S+1)$. Thus, it can be a candidate for the representation of $so(3)$ in $V = \mathbb C^{2S+1}$, generating the representation of $SO(3)$ in this space.

Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer certainly goes in the right direction, but you are missing one point. You should use the action of $SU(2)$ on homogeneous polynomials of degree $\ell$. Initially, this can be done for any degree $\ell$ and the resulting space has dimension $\ell+1$. (A basis is formed by the elements $z^iw^{\ell-i}$ for $i=0,\dots,\ell$.) This gives you a representation of $\mathfrak{su}(2)\cong\mathfrak{so}(3)$ in any complex dimension. Now it remains to show that in odd dimensions, i.e. in the case of homogeneous polynomials of even degree, there is a corresponding representation of the group $SO(3)$. To do this, you have to observe that the isomorphism of the Lie algebras corresponds to the fact that there is a surjective homomorphism $SU(2)\to SO(3)$ with kernel $\{\pm\mathbb I\}$. This implies that representations of $SO(3)$ correspond to representations of $SU(2)$ on which $-\mathbb I$ acts trivially. In the case of homogeneous polynomials of degree $\ell$, $-\mathbb I$ acts by multiplication by $(-1)^\ell$, which implies the claim.

Comment: Haven't I used the action of SU(2) on homogeneous polynomials of degree $l$? Or am I not completely understanding what you mean?

What bothers me is that since I want to find the representation of SO(3) in some space ($V=\mathbb C^{2S+1}$), I must start from SO(3). Therefore, I am not sure, although $SO(2)\to SO(3)$ is a homomorphism, whether or not the reverse map $SO(3)\to SO(2)$ is a homomorphism?

Comment: You have used the action of $SU(2)$, but you have not used the fact that the dimension of the representation is odd. The natural homomorphism $SU(2)\to SO(3)$ does not admit a "reverse map", but there is an induced homomorphism $SU(2)/\{\pm\mathbb I\}\to SO(3)$ which is an isomorphism and thus does admit an inverse. A representation of $SU(2)/\{\pm\mathbb I\}$ is (more or less by definition) the same as a representation of $SU(2)$ on which $-\mathbb I$ acts as the identity, and such representations are equivalent to representations of $SO(3)$.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have specified $S$ to be integers, in fact I forgot that it is generally half-integer so $2S+1 \in \mathbb Z$. If this change were incorporated in my proof, then is it still necessary to separate the distinction between even and odd $l$? Actually I know that the map $SU(2) \to SO(3)$ is "double-cover" because $g,-g \in SU(2)$ is mapped into the same element in $SO(3)$, but what is the difference between $SU(2)/\{\pm \mathbb I\}$ and $SU(2)$?

Comment: The existence of the two fold covering $SU(2)\to SO(3)$ means that $SO(3)$ is isomorphic to the quotient of $SU(2)$ by the subgroup consisting of $\mathbb I$ and $-\mathbb I$. This says that any homomorphism from $SO(3)$ to a Lie group $G$ gives rise to a homomorphism of $SU(2)$, but conversely a homomorphism of $SU(2)$ gives rise to a homomorphism of $SO(3)$ only if $-\mathbb I$ is mapped to the unit element of $G$. This means that representations of $SO(3)$ correspond to "half of" the representations of $SU(2)$ (namely the odd dimensional ones).